# How to fix problem with too many interprocess pipes being created?

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am quite new to Python so please don't judge me :) I am a network engineer working on python program that connects to over 600 devices to gather certain data. It is using multiprocessing. I have decided to basically run all at once since the server i am using can handle this approach just fine and it tremendously speeds up whole process. I have just noticed that that my program uses insane amount of file descriptors (over 200K). I was able to track that down to interprocess (i am assuming) pipes being created. It look like each of consecutively spawned processes opens a pipe not just to its parent (which is the main program), but also to all of his 'brothers' that were spawned before him. I honestly have no idea if this is normal behavior or something is wrong with my code. I do need for processes to send data back to their parent but i definitely do not need for them to communicate between each other. Is there anything i can do to prevent that full mesh of pipes being created when i spawn child processes ?

This shows the issue:

root@vf1netcat2:~# lsof -p 15531 | grep pipe
python3 15531 netcat    4r  FIFO   0,12      0t0 334887 pipe
python3 15531 netcat    5w  FIFO   0,12      0t0 334887 pipe
python3 15531 netcat    6r  FIFO   0,12      0t0 334888 pipe
python3 15531 netcat    7w  FIFO   0,12      0t0 334888 pipe
python3 15531 netcat    9w  FIFO   0,12      0t0 334889 pipe
root@vf1netcat2:~# lsof -p 15532 | grep pipe
python3 15532 netcat    4r  FIFO   0,12      0t0 334887 pipe
python3 15532 netcat    5w  FIFO   0,12      0t0 334887 pipe
python3 15532 netcat    6r  FIFO   0,12      0t0 334888 pipe
python3 15532 netcat    7w  FIFO   0,12      0t0 334888 pipe
python3 15532 netcat    8r  FIFO   0,12      0t0 334889 pipe
python3 15532 netcat   10w  FIFO   0,12      0t0 334890 pipe
root@vf1netcat2:~# lsof -p 15533 | grep pipe
python3 15533 netcat    4r  FIFO   0,12      0t0 334887 pipe
python3 15533 netcat    5w  FIFO   0,12      0t0 334887 pipe
python3 15533 netcat    6r  FIFO   0,12      0t0 334888 pipe
python3 15533 netcat    7w  FIFO   0,12      0t0 334888 pipe
python3 15533 netcat    8r  FIFO   0,12      0t0 334889 pipe
python3 15533 netcat    9r  FIFO   0,12      0t0 334890 pipe
python3 15533 netcat   11w  FIFO   0,12      0t0 334891 pipe

...

root@vf1netcat2:~# lsof -p 15735 | grep pipe | wc -l
209
root@vf1netcat2:~# lsof -p 16035 | grep pipe | wc -l
509
root@vf1netcat2:~# lsof -p 16100 | grep pipe | wc -l


root@vf1netcat2:~# lsof | wc -l
3838
root@vf1netcat2:~# lsof | wc -l
184686
root@vf1netcat2:~# lsof | wc -l
237127
root@vf1netcat2:~# lsof | wc -l
228187

This is how i am spawning child processes:

```
def execute_data_processing_function(data_list: List[Any], data_processing_function: Callable[..., List[Any]], *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> List[Any]:
    """ Execute generic data processing function in single or multiprocess manner and return merged list of results """

    if SINGLE_PROCESS_MODE:
        results = [data_processing_function(_, *args, **kwargs) for _ in data_list]

    else:
        with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=len(data_list)) as executor:
            process_pool = [executor.submit(data_processing_function, _, *args, **kwargs) for _ in data_list]

        results = [_.result() for _ in process_pool if not _.exception() and _.result()]

    return [_ for __ in results for _ in __]
```

Comment: To format the code, select it and type `ctrl-k` [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) ... [more Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) ... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: There is a diagram of concurrent.futures process in the source: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/concurrent/futures/process.py#L6 .

Comment: Thanks, i am definitely going to do more research on Linux multiprocessing. In general main drive for this project for me is a learning experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to look at [`set_start_method()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.set_start_method).  Using the `'forkserver'` method would eliminate the extra pipe file descriptors.